# Grid System on IE

Tags: css

I would like to use CSS Grid and make it work on IE but I have no idea why it doesn't work. On Chrome it looks very good.

This is how my code looks like:

```
.container {
  color: #fff;

  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;

  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

  -ms-grid-gap: 10px 10px;
      grid-gap: 10px 10px;

  -ms-grid-template-areas: 
  "header header header"
  "aside main section"
  "footer footer footer";
      grid-template-areas: 
      "header header header"
      "aside main section"
      "footer footer footer";

}
.container > * {
  background-color: red;  
  padding: 30px;
}

header {
  -ms-grid-area: header;
      grid-area: header;
}
aside {
  -ms-grid-area: aside;
      grid-area: aside;
}
section {
  -ms-grid-area: section;
      grid-area: section;
}
main {
  -ms-grid-area: main;
      grid-area: main;
}
footer {
  -ms-grid-area: footer;
      grid-area: footer;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/erbnw6wm/1/

I couldn't find any prefixes for `grid-gap`, `grid-template-areas` and `grid-areas`. I just put a `-ms-` before them but that might be wrong.

Is there a solution or do I have to wait until IE supports them?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, I was 10 times on that page but it says IE supports it with the prefix -ms- but it's not supporting `grid-gap`, `grid-template-areas` and `grid-areas`. That's what I am trying to say.

Comment: @RezaSaadati, as the page says, partial support in IE refers to supporting an [older version](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407) of the specification. Meaning, if it's not in that version of the specification, it's not going to be in IE (prefixed or otherwise)

Comment: IE is not updated anymore, edge is the browser that users should use now. So IE will never have full grid support.